# Javascript Runtime Exception

Tags: javascript, html5, try-catch

Estou estou tentando fazer uma chamada de arquivos dinâmica onde tenho um `input` que recebe um nome e é carregado um arquivo com este nome no `<source>` no js, quando a pessoa digita um nome de arquivo que não existe na pasta precisaria exibir uma mensagem de erro e não executar o `play()`, mas por algum motivo no código a baixo o `catch` não pega o erro. Pensei em fazer uma verificação se o arquivo existe antes de atribuir o nome, mas eu gostaria de uma solução simples sem precisar de API ou coisa do gênero e não encontrei. 
No final eu preciso de um jeito ou de tratar o erro `GET net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` ou de verificar de uma forma simples, sem precisar de API, se o arquivo existe antes de atribuir (caso seja possível, claro).

Segue o Código:

```
function play (element) {
    try {
        audioElement[played] = document.createElement('audio');

        audioElement[played].innerHTML = '<source src="../_songs/' + element.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("musica-location")[0].value + '.mp3"'+ ' type="audio/mpeg" />';
        audioElement[played].play();
    } catch (err) {
        alert("Erro, arquivo não encontrado", err);
    }


    element.setAttribute("data-audio", played++);
}
```

Comment: Acredito que a melhor maneira é verificar se o arquivo existe, pois o _TryCatch_ que está fazendo não está dando erro na execução do código e sim erro de arquivo não encontrado, o que não cairia no _catch_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro `ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, na verdade, não é um erro do JS, mas sim um erro que o browser joga para que voce possa debugar o seu código com mais facilidade, por esse motivo voce nunca vai conseguir pegar ele com o catch no código.

Como já descrevem algumas respostas abaixo como:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249584/how-to-catch-err-file-not-found-errors-in-javascript
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657121/how-can-i-check-existence-of-a-file-with-javascript

Algumas opções estão disponíveis, entre elas a leitura paralela do arquivo via AJAX com jQuery mais ou menos deste modo:

```
$.get("/caminho/do/arquivo", function(data, status) {  
   console.log("Status do arquivo: "+status); 
   //...resto do seu código...
});
```

Uma outra opção é tentar utilizar a função de erro que está *built-in* no HTML da tag `<audio>` como `<audio onerror=...>`conforme esse link:

- http://www.w3schools.com/TagS/av_event_error.asp

Você pode tanto utilizar uma função pré existente como `<audio onerror='suafuncao'>` ou então utilizar o próprio JS para criar um listener para este evento no seu elemento:

```
object.onerror = function(){
  //...
};
```